# The Visual Studio can't find Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have created a new MVC Web App project in the Visual Studio 2019 (Targeting .NET 5.0)

Now I want to install EntityFrameworkCore, but it doesn't appear on the list when I search in the NuGet manager. If I type "entity", only 3 options appear. If I type more than that, nothing more appears.

[image]

I also tried typing (in the console manager)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 5.0.11
```

and getting this error:

```
    `Install-Package : NU1101: Unable to find package` 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packag
    es
    At line:1 char:1
    + Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 5.0.11
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

I also tried cleaning and building the project several times. The VS2019 I recently just installed.
What might be wrong?

Comment: Looks like it's only searching the offline packages folder. In Package Manager Settings, what sources do you have added?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with what sources I've added? So far I did add or install any packages. It's a clean VS, and this is the first package that I'm trying to install

Comment: Look at the package manager settings, what sources are listed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Visual Studio go to `Tools`  ►  `Options`. Select `NuGet Package Manager`. Check that you have `Package sources:` is including `nuget.org` set to `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`:

[image]

Then `Tools` ► `NuGet Package Manager` ► `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...`. Open the `Browse` tab.

Select ***nuget.org*** in the `Package source:` combo-box:

[image]